# Every local martingale with respect to the Brownian filtration has its continuous version.

Tags: brownian-motion, martingales, filtrations, local-martingales

I would appreciate some help on the following.

In class, we said that **Every local martingale with respect to the Brownian filtration has its continuous version.**

To prove this, it is apprently enough to show this for:

- martingales instead of local martingales and
- finite intervals.

I think it has something to do with the martingale representation theorem, but I am completely lost and I would really like to know why is either one of the listed substitute statements enough.

Thanks! :)